# PHP Parsing Problem - &nbsp; and Â

Tags: php, html, parsing, character-encoding

When I try to parse some html that has `&nbsp;` sprinkled through it and then `echo` it, the `&nbsp;` "turns into" this character: Â. Also, `html_entity_decode()` and `str_replace()` doesn't change it.

Why is this happening? How can I remove the Â's?

Comment: it "turns" or is interpreted by the browser as such?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [non-breaking space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) exist in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) of two bytes: `0xC2` and `0xA0`.

When those bytes are represented in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) (a single-byte encoding) instead of UTF-8 (a multi-byte encoding) then those bytes becomes respectively the characters `Â` and another non-breaking space  .

Apparently you're parsing the HTML using UTF-8 and echoing the results using ISO-8859-1. To fix this problem, you need to *either* parse HTML using ISO-8859-1 *or* echo the results using UTF-8. I'd recommend to use UTF-8 all the way. Go through the [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224211620/http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) to align it all out.

#### See also:

- ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Answer (score 2):

```
html_entity_decode("&nbsp;") == '\xa0'
```

I think by design, I don't understand why str_replace does not work for you, try this snippet:

```
$nbsp = html_entity_decode("&nbsp;");
$s = html_entity_decode("[&nbsp;]");
$s = str_replace($nbsp, " ", $s);
echo $s;
```

perhaps \xa0 it's not a valid unicode string, so using the result of the html_entity_decode() may be more appropriate for text replacement instead of \xa0.

BalusC explanation looks plausible you may trying to insert utf-8 \xc2\xa0 in the the then trying to display it as latin instead of utf8, if you want to use unicode stuff you should keep utf-8 encoding everywhere, from the charset of the server to the db, since you will have the same problem when using e.g. `&agrave;`

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) can also do the trick:

```
preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","", $var);
```