# Does html_entity_decode replaces &nbsp; also? If not how to replace it?

Tags: php, html, string, whitespace, html-entities

I have a situation where I am  passing a string to a function. I want to convert `&nbsp;` to " " (a blank space) before passing it to function. Does `html_entity_decode` does it?

If not how to do it?

I am aware of `str_replace` but is there any other way out?

Comment: I need a suggestion for it, so that I can try out.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9871045/620410) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515394/620410) is a similar question answered (with focus on different encodings).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Quote from [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) manual:

> You might wonder why
>   `trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'));`
>   doesn't reduce the string to an empty
>   string, that's because the `'&nbsp;'`
>   entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is
>   stripped by trim()) but ASCII code 160
>   (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1
>   characterset.

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the ascii character #160 to a space:

```
<?php
$a = html_entity_decode('>&nbsp;<');
echo 'before ' . $a . PHP_EOL;
$a = str_replace("\xA0", ' ', $a);
echo ' after ' . $a . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: If you are working with UTF-8 encoded strings you should replace \xC2\xA0 . 
  $a = html_entity_decode('>&nbsp;<', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  echo 'before ' . $a . PHP_EOL;
  $a = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", ' ', $a);
  echo ' after ' . $a . PHP_EOL;

Comment: I've been struggling a lot with the data I retrieve from a `contenteditable` element, all `rtrim` and `preg_replace` attempts failed. I've also been trying to filter stuff with JavaScript before shooting it with `$.ajax()`, also failed. So now I do `str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $value)` and then `preg_replace('/\s+$/','',$value)`. It works, though not too elegant. If someone has suggestions, please tell me,

Answer (score 5):

html_entity_decode does convert `&nbsp;` to a space, just not a "simple" one (ASCII 32), but a non-breaking space (ASCII 160) (as this is the definition of `&nbsp;`).

If you need to convert to ASCII 32, you still need a `str_replace()`, or, depending on your situation, a `preg_match("/s+", ' ', $string)` to convert all kinds of whitespace to simple spaces.

Comment: $str = preg_replace('%\s+%u', ' ', $str);

Answer (score 5):

### YES

See PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php.

Carefully read the **Notes**, maybe that s the issue you are facing：

> You might wonder why trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;')); 
>   doesn't reduce the string to an empty string,
>   that's because the ' ' entity is not ASCII code 32 
>   (which is stripped by trim()) but ASCII code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 characterset.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is a viable solution for most cases but I used `trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($html), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));`in my most recent application. The addition of `htmlspecialchars_decode()` initially was the only thing that would actually strip them.