# how do I find non UTF-8 characters in mysql (mariadb) data using mysql or PHP

Tags: php, mariadb, utf8mb4

I am using

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.39-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

PHP 8.2.13 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2023 09:33:30) (NTS)

I would like to use either or both of these to find data within mysql where the mysql data columns have been declared to be in character set utf8mb4, collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but where the characters in the data are not actually valid UTF-8 characters.

I'm pretty sure that I have Mojobake, latin1, or other non-valid characters in my data.  My data comes from governmental databases that do not really screen what reporters to the database enter and do not have a consistent character encoding.  Some of the characters certainly look like garbage characters.

However, I've tried various ways of automatically detecting these, and none of them seem to work.

I've tried within mysql (I'm pretty sure that all of the defaults e.g. SET NAMES are set correctly):

```
select field_name from table_name
WHERE CONVERT(field_name, binary) RLIKE '([\\xC0-\\xC1]|[\\xF5-\\xFF]|\\xE0[\\x80-\\x9F]|\\xF0[\\x80-\\x8F]|[\\xC2-\\xDF](?![\\x80-\\xBF])|[\\xE0-\\xEF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]{2})|[\\xF0-\\xF4](?![\\x80-\\xBF]{3})|(?<=[\\x00-\\x7F\\xF5-\\xFF])[\\x80-\\xBF]|(?<![\\xC2-\\xDF]|[\\xE0-\\xEF]|[\\xE0-\\xEF][\\x80-\\xBF]|[\\xF0-\\xF4]|[\\xF0-\\xF4][\\x80-\\xBF]|[\\xF0-\\xF4][\\x80-\\xBF]{2})[\\x80-\\xBF]|(?<=[\\xE0-\\xEF])[\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF])|(?<=[\\xF0-\\xF4])[\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]{2})|(?<=[\\xF0-\\xF4][\\x80-\\xBF])[\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]))'
```

I've tried within PHP retrieving the mysql data into $string (I'm pretty sure that I've set all the PHP defaults to use UTF-8) and then:

1.

```
if (preg_match("//u", $string)) {
  // $string is valid UTF-8
}
```

2. 

```
if (mb_detect_encoding($string,"UTF-8",TRUE)) {
  // $string is valid UTF-8
}
```

But none of these methods detect the characters that look wrong.

Sample data

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample; 
 CREATE TABLE sample ( data text DEFAULT NULL ) 
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 
 INSERT INTO sample VALUES (
 'Mr. Geoffrey H. Yost, Oï¿½Melveny & Myers LLP')
 ,('Valero Refining Company ï¿½ California')
 ,('El Paso Merchant Energy ï¿½ Petroleum Company')
 ,('PapÃ© Group/IFCO')
 ,('Huntonsï¿½ SureCrop Farm Svc Inc dba SureCrop Farm')
 ,('developed, manufactured, marketed, tested, and sold the electronic diesel control that allowed Mercedes to manipulate emissions controls and that Bosch marketed ¢€š¬Ã…¡¬ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦¡€š¬Ã…¡¬Ãƒ€ ‚¬„¢‚¬Å¡¬¦¢€š¬Ã…¡¬ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦€š¬Ã…€œClean Diesel¢€š¬Ã…¡¬ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦¡€š¬Ã…¡¬€š¬Ã…¡<9d> to the public.');
```

Comment: some sample data with create table would help understand your problem

Comment: Here's one more record with different kinds of problematic characters: 'developed, manufactured, marketed, tested, and sold the electronic diesel control that allowed Mercedes to manipulate emissions controls and that Bosch marketed ¢€š¬Ã…¡¬ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦¡€š¬Ã…¡¬Ãƒ€ ‚¬„¢‚¬Å¡¬¦¢€š¬Ã…¡¬ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦€š¬Ã…€œClean Diesel¢€š¬Ã…¡¬ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦¡€š¬Ã…¡¬€š¬Ã…¡<9d> to the public.'  I have no idea how to copy them here while preserving their encoding.

Comment: best would be to import he data correctly with the right character set but you could do something like https://dbfiddle.uk/N2Hxf475 in php you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088258/remove-hidden-non-ascii-characters-php-or-mysql

Comment: It might be a small thing but I just want to make sure your mental model of this is correct. All of the _characters_ in the sample data you provided are valid Unicode characters and all Unicode characters can be encoded as UTF-8. What you are looking for are byte sequences that are not being interpreted as the character set that you expect. If the data is in the database it is probably too late because "something" has already converted it. This [demo](https://3v4l.org/kQL6m) shows how mb_convert_encoding will replace invalid byte sequences with the substitution character, thus making it valid.

Comment: "Looks wrong" doesn't necessarily mean that it's not valid UTF8, and the data you've posted could well be perfectly-valid UTF8. What it actually looks like is that someone took already-properly-encoded UTF8 text and ran it through something like `utf8_encode()` which turned it into valid UTF8 gibberish because it interprets its input as though it were ISO-8859-1 encoded.

Comment: It would be better to investigate the code that _put that data there like that_ to see if it's possible to reverse what it has done to the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions that I investigate the code that put the data there: as I wrote above I cant do that because the data arrive as the output of a extended black box that I have no access to.  What I didn't understand is that all Unicode characters can be encoded as UTF-8 and therefore there literally can't be an invalid UTF-8 character (I guess?)  So my problem can't be answered as is.  I can only try to detect common replacement characters.

Comment: I'll reconsider my comment above: as one of the answers below mentions, there are error messages like "invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'A2809A'".  Therefore, it can't be that every possible character is a valid utf8mb4 character.  The three methods that I tried in my original post were all methods that someone used to detect invalid utf-8, so it must be possible in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The original data was stored in utf8 or utf8mb4 but incorrectly decoded using an 8-bit encoding, like latin1.

`'ï¿½'` was unicode replacement character `�` which usually indicates that some other character could not correctly be converted before.

You can easily check this with e.g. python

```
>>> 'Ã©'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf8')
'é'
>>> 'ï¿½'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf8')
'�'
```

Currently the utf8mb4 character set contains 1,112,064 valid characters, but an 8-bit character set only contains 255 characters. This means that your data theoretically might have 1.111.809 wrong multibyte characters, which weren't  converted correctly.

Comment: OK -- I've got approximately a terabyte of data.  Is there any way to detect the bad patches without looking through it?  It's not a database-wide problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did load your sample data, after that I did, base on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407998/724039):

```
-- Because I do not like selecting text with weird characters:
alter table sample add id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

select 
   id, 
   data, 
   convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4) L 
from sample 
where id=4;
```

This produces:

| id | data | L |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | PapÃ© Group/IFCO | Papé Group/IFCO |

It seems that the import you did from the external databases incorrectly imported LATIN1 as UTF8.

Your statement: "... *governmental databases that do not really screen what reporters to the database enter* ..." might be incorrect, and it might be that you simply imported it using wrong assumtpions.

A solution, to find those errors, might be:

```
select 
  data d1,
  convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4) d2 
from sample 
where data<>convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4);
```

But this leads to the error:

> ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'

So, in stead of correcting the error, you might want to restart, and do the import in a correct way?

Also try this:

```
select id, data, convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4) as d2 
from sample 
where data collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci != convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4) and id between 5 and 5;

select id, data, convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4) as d2 
from sample 
where data collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci != convert(cast(convert(data using  latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4) and id >= 5;
```

The first statement does not throw a warning, but the second statement does. The warning is: `Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'A2809A'`

The difference between those 2 last statement, and the warning give, might lead to an almost not possible way of finding this *wrong* characters.

I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/U-nOWAs1) with the statements used.

Comment: "So, in stead of correcting the error, you might want to restart, and do the import in a correct way?"  I can only repeat that data arrive in a file that contains characters in a mixture of character encodings.  It is not simply a latin1 file that I've loaded as utf8.  I think that providing sample data was a mistake since people seem to be choosing small parts of the sample data to diagnose or fix, and that does not solve the problem.

Comment: The problem might be easier to solve when such a datafile (or a small reproduction with the problem ) is present. (as a binary downloadable from somewhere, although stackoverflow needs/wants to have al the data in the question, but does not give an option to share a binary file, and I do not want to copy/past text from my browser with the change the problem changes....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Georg Richter, Chris Haas, and other contributors for clarifying this.  I'm going to try answering my own question.

It's possible to have an invalid UTF-8 sequence -- from the Unicode FAQ: "A sequence such as <110xxxxx2 0xxxxxxx2> is illegal, and must never be generated. When faced with this illegal byte sequence while transforming or interpreting, a UTF-8 conformant process must treat the first byte 110xxxxx2 as an illegal termination error: for example, either signaling an error, filtering the byte out, or representing the byte with a marker such as FFFD (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)."

However, the incoming data that I get already has been "converted" into UTF-8 by being run through the process above.  Therefore, all of the characters are valid UTF-8 characters.  The three methods that I presented in my question might work to detect invalid UTF-8 characters, but they don't work on these data because everything is already a valid UTF-8 character.

To find improperly converted characters, I can use mysql to find character variables where length(field_name) <> char_length(field_name) (this should detect any multibyte character) and then test the multibyte characters for the replacement character or any of a number of other characters copied from an ad hoc list that I create of characters that I never expect to see in well formed data.  For instance, "ÃƒÆ" is apparently a valid UTF-8 character (or more than one) but I don't expect to ever see it used for anything.  I can keep adding these characters to a table somewhere until my detector works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

- ï¿½ is hex EFBFBD, which is BOM, which I discuss [*here*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark)

  Some editors and other text creation tools *start* a document with the BOM to indicate that it is UTF-8 encoded.  It looks like you have constructed data from the first part of a document, and that is where that string comes from.
- Perhaps a global `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'ï¿½', '')` would be part of an `UPDATE` to get rid of that.  (Caution: it will take a long time if the table is large.)
- This will find "names" encoded in UTF-8:

  ```
  WHERE HEX(name) REGEXP '^(..)*[CDEFcdef]'
  ```
- This will find those that need utf8mb4, not just utf8mb3:

  ```
  WHERE HEX(name) REGEXP '^(..)*[Ff]'
  ```
- `Ã©` is Mojibake for `é`.  If you see that, diagnose it with [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)
- "Character set" refers to the encoding; "Collation" refers to sorting.  Your question is only about `CHARACTER SET`.
- `SET NAMES latin1;` immediately after connecting to MySQL/MariaDB *server* will announce that the characters in the *client* (eg, your govt db) are encoded as `latin1`.  Possibly you are running with a `utf8` default.
- If a single dataset has a mixture of encodings, all hope is lost!
- `ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦¡€š¬Ã…¡¬` may be "double-encoding" (see this StackOverflow link).
- *Some* bad text can be "fixed", *but only* after identifying what caused it to be wrong.  If the data came from multiple sources, there may be multiple *different* fixes needed.  Furthermore, applying the wrong fix will only make the data *much* harder to fix.
- May I suggest that you start over on that terabyte.  Load each source into a *separate* table, then verify the encoding.  If it is broken, see if a `SET NAMES` will fix it (and re-load).  This will let you isolate the different fixes.  Luuk pointed out one `CONVERT(...)` that works for *one* case.  I do not have an answer for `A2809A`; it is not UTF-8, nor does it look like valid stuff in any of the supported charsets.

Comment: Thanks for this: these notes are helpful.  But "If a single dataset has a mixture of encodings, all hope is lost!" is the case and is what I meant by"[does] not have a consistent character encoding".  I think that it was a mistake for me to supply a small sample: I didn't want people to tell me how to fix the sample since there is every other conceivable kind of problem as well.  I just wanted a detector to find/screen for them.

Comment: @RichP - If a _single column_ has both `ÃƒÆ’‚¬¦` and legitimate characters, then it is very difficult to "fix" the table. Once you screen for them, what will you do then?

Comment: There are 4 things I can do without an auto-fix that a detector would enable: 1) report problems back to the governmental agency that collected the data, 2) warn users, 3) auto-fix some very common problems, 4) manually fix some problems in very important data fields

Comment: If you are gathering data from multiple sources, and you don't have sufficient clout, there is no hope to get them to be consistent.  _You_ must deal with the messes they give you.