# I save the data in json file and upload to gcs but got this unicode-context. "ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"

Tags: scala, unicode, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, spotify-scio

I'new for GCP Tools and Scala. I have this issue.
I create the job to upload json file to GCS bucket via DataflowRunner. But, when I check the data inside file. it shows like this. ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ( Actually it should show Thai Language). But, when i dev in local and run with command DirectRunner. It show data correctly. I don't sure what happen. As my understand, it may have some incompatible Unicode between Dataflow and GCS. Can anyone suggest me. Thank you so much.

Appreciated So much :)

```
        val query = sc.bigQuerySelect(sql).map{
            row => 
                val user_name: String = row.getString("user_name")     
                val decryptJson = parse(user_name).getOrElse(Json.Null)
                val name = decryptJson.hcursor.downField("a").downField("name").focus.get.asString.getOrElse("")  
                    TableRow(
                        ("name" -> name),
                       
                    )
        }
        val res = query.filter(_ != null)
        print(nonEmptyQueryResult)
        res.saveAsTableRowJsonFile(outputPath, numShards=50)
        sc.close()
```

sbt "runMain dev.test --project=test --runner=DataflowRunner --workerMachineType=n1-standard-1

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77668599/3439404), mostly about `ï¿½`, a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case   for `�` (U+FFFD,  *Replacement Character*)… Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).