# PHP: How to use the Twitter API's data to convert URLs, mentions, and hastags in tweets to links?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm really stumped on how Twitter expects users of its API to convert the plaintext tweets it sends to properly linked HTML.

Here's the deal: Twitter's JSON API sends this set of information back when you request the detailed data for a tweet:

```
{
    "created_at":"Wed Jul 18 01:03:31 +0000 2012",
    "id":225395341250412544,
    "id_str":"225395341250412544",
    "text":"This is a test tweet. #boring @nbc http://t.co/LUfDreY6 #skronk @crux http://t.co/VpuMlaDs @twitter",
    "source":"web",
    "truncated":false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
    "user": <REDACTED>,
    "geo":null,
    "coordinates":null,
    "place":null,
    "contributors":null,
    "retweet_count":0,
    "entities":{
        "hashtags":[
            {
                "text":"boring",
                "indices":[22,29]
            },
            {
                "text":"skronk",
                "indices":[56,63]
            }
        ],
        "urls":[
            {
                "url":"http://t.co/LUfDreY6",
                "expanded_url":"http://www.twitter.com",
                "display_url":"twitter.com",
                "indices":[35,55]
            },
            {
                "url":"http://t.co/VpuMlaDs",
                "expanded_url":"http://www.example.com",
                "display_url":"example.com",
                "indices":[70,90]
            }
        ],
        "user_mentions":[
            {
                "screen_name":"nbc",
                "name":"NBC",
                "id":26585095,
                "id_str":"26585095",
                "indices":[30,34]
            },
            {
                "screen_name":"crux",
                "name":"Z. D. Smith",
                "id":407213,
                "id_str":"407213",
                "indices":[64,69]
            },
            {
                "screen_name":"twitter",
                "name":"Twitter",
                "id":783214,
                "id_str":"783214",
                "indices":[91,99]
            }
        ]
    },
    "favorited":false,
    "retweeted":false,
    "possibly_sensitive":false
}
```

The interesting parts, for this question, are the `text` element and the entries in the `hashtags`, `user_mentions`, and `urls` arrays. Twitter is telling us where in the `text` element the hastags, mentions, and urls appear with the `indices` arrays... so here's the crux of the question:

How do you *use* those `indices` arrays?

You can't just use them straight up by looping over each link element with something like [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php), since replacing the first link element in the `text` will invalidate all the index values for subsequent link elements. You also can't use [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)'s array functionality, since it only works when you give it an array of strings for the first arg, rather than a single string (I've tested this. The results are... strange).

Is there some function that can simultaneously replace multiple index-delimited substrings in a single string with different replacement strings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you have to do to use the indices twitter provides straight up with a simple replace is collect the replacements you want to make and then sort them backwards. You can probably find a more clever way to build $entities, I wanted them optional anyway, so I KISS as far as that went.

Either way, my point here was just to show that you don't need to explode the string and character count and whatnot. Regardless of how you do it, all you need to to is start at the end and work to the beginning of the string, and the index twitter has is still valid.

```
<?php 

function json_tweet_text_to_HTML($tweet, $links=true, $users=true, $hashtags=true)
{
    $return = $tweet->text;

    $entities = array();

    if($links && is_array($tweet->entities->urls))
    {
        foreach($tweet->entities->urls as $e)
        {
            $temp["start"] = $e->indices[0];
            $temp["end"] = $e->indices[1];
            $temp["replacement"] = "<a href='".$e->expanded_url."' target='_blank'>".$e->display_url."</a>";
            $entities[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    if($users && is_array($tweet->entities->user_mentions))
    {
        foreach($tweet->entities->user_mentions as $e)
        {
            $temp["start"] = $e->indices[0];
            $temp["end"] = $e->indices[1];
            $temp["replacement"] = "<a href='https://twitter.com/".$e->screen_name."' target='_blank'>@".$e->screen_name."</a>";
            $entities[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    if($hashtags && is_array($tweet->entities->hashtags))
    {
        foreach($tweet->entities->hashtags as $e)
        {
            $temp["start"] = $e->indices[0];
            $temp["end"] = $e->indices[1];
            $temp["replacement"] = "<a href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/".$e->text."?src=hash' target='_blank'>#".$e->text."</a>";
            $entities[] = $temp;
        }
    }

    usort($entities, function($a,$b){return($b["start"]-$a["start"]);});


    foreach($entities as $item)
    {
        $return = substr_replace($return, $item["replacement"], $item["start"], $item["end"] - $item["start"]);
    }

    return($return);
}


?>
```

Comment: *facepalm*... Why didn't ***I*** think of that??

Comment: Works for me... I added an additional bit of code at the top as when you retrieve retweets they sometimes contain ellipses. Twitter recommends you use the retweet_status and its entities in such circumstances: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#retweets

Comment: **WARNING:** `substr_replace` is not multibyte (utf-8) compatible. Strings with (in my case) accented characters will result in incorrect indices!

Comment: Any fix for the issue @Tim is highlighting ?

Comment: @MbengueAssane Try [`utf8_substr_replace`](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2012/09/a-utf-8-aware-substr_replace-for-use-in-app-net/).

Answer (score 13):

Ok so I needed to do exactly this and I solved it. Here is the function I wrote. https://gist.github.com/3337428

```
function parse_message( &$tweet ) {
    if ( !empty($tweet['entities']) ) {
        $replace_index = array();
        $append = array();
        $text = $tweet['text'];
        foreach ($tweet['entities'] as $area => $items) {
            $prefix = false;
            $display = false;
            switch ( $area ) {
                case 'hashtags':
                    $find   = 'text';
                    $prefix = '#';
                    $url    = 'https://twitter.com/search/?src=hash&q=%23';
                    break;
                case 'user_mentions':
                    $find   = 'screen_name';
                    $prefix = '@';
                    $url    = 'https://twitter.com/';
                    break;
                case 'media':
                    $display = 'media_url_https';
                    $href    = 'media_url_https';
                    $size    = 'small';
                    break;
                case 'urls':
                    $find    = 'url';
                    $display = 'display_url';
                    $url     = "expanded_url";
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ( $area == 'media' ) {
                    // We can display images at the end of the tweet but sizing needs to added all the way to the top.
                    // $append[$item->$display] = "<img src=\"{$item->$href}:$size\" />";
                }else{
                    $msg     = $display ? $prefix.$item->$display : $prefix.$item->$find;
                    $replace = $prefix.$item->$find;
                    $href    = isset($item->$url) ? $item->$url : $url;
                    if (!(strpos($href, 'http') === 0)) $href = "http://".$href;
                    if ( $prefix ) $href .= $item->$find;
                    $with = "<a href=\"$href\">$msg</a>";
                    $replace_index[$replace] = $with;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($replace_index as $replace => $with) $tweet['text'] = str_replace($replace,$with,$tweet['text']);
        foreach ($append as $add) $tweet['text'] .= $add;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good base implementation, but it has bugs. It places display_url instead of expanded url as the a href (broken links with "...") and it does some weird replacements for hashtags and @screen_names.

Comment: I have edited this to work more consistently with the current API.

Answer (score 7):

It's an edge case but the use of str_replace() in Styledev's answer could cause issues if one entity is contained within another.  For example, "I'm a genius! #me #mensa" could become "I'm a genius! [#me](http://example.com) [#me](http://example.com)nsa" if the shorter entity is substituted first.

This solution avoids that problem:

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyperlinks hashtags, twitter names, and urls within the text of a tweet
 * 
 * @param object $apiResponseTweetObject A json_decoded() one of these: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets
 * @return string The tweet's text with hyperlinks added
 */
function linkEntitiesWithinText($apiResponseTweetObject) {

    // Convert tweet text to array of one-character strings
    // $characters = str_split($apiResponseTweetObject->text);
    $characters = preg_split('//u', $apiResponseTweetObject->text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    // Insert starting and closing link tags at indices...

    // ... for @user_mentions
    foreach ($apiResponseTweetObject->entities->user_mentions as $entity) {
        $link = "https://twitter.com/" . $entity->screen_name;          
        $characters[$entity->indices[0]] = "<a href=\"$link\">" . $characters[$entity->indices[0]];
        $characters[$entity->indices[1] - 1] .= "</a>";         
    }               

    // ... for #hashtags
    foreach ($apiResponseTweetObject->entities->hashtags as $entity) {
        $link = "https://twitter.com/search?q=%23" . $entity->text;         
        $characters[$entity->indices[0]] = "<a href=\"$link\">" . $characters[$entity->indices[0]];
        $characters[$entity->indices[1] - 1] .= "</a>";         
    }

    // ... for http://urls
    foreach ($apiResponseTweetObject->entities->urls as $entity) {
        $link = $entity->expanded_url;          
        $characters[$entity->indices[0]] = "<a href=\"$link\">" . $characters[$entity->indices[0]];
        $characters[$entity->indices[1] - 1] .= "</a>";         
    }

    // ... for media
    foreach ($apiResponseTweetObject->entities->media as $entity) {
        $link = $entity->expanded_url;          
        $characters[$entity->indices[0]] = "<a href=\"$link\">" . $characters[$entity->indices[0]];
        $characters[$entity->indices[1] - 1] .= "</a>";         
    }

    // Convert array back to string
    return implode('', $characters);

}
?>
```

Comment: I got this error :Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$text in /Users/#/Sites/twitter/test.php on line 9

Comment: Yes, and it was working, but it was leaving parts of the twitts out :(

Comment: This code works great for me, although I'm receiving a "PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" on the for media foreach statement. Is there any way I can prevent that warning from being triggered?

Comment: I just added a if (is_array($apiResponseTweetObject->entities->media)) { before the foreach loop.

Comment: From all the answers this is the only one that works as expected for me, for Tweets & Retweets and with correct hashtags. Still can't believe that Twitter doesn't provide an easier way to do this...

Answer (score 6):

Jeff's solution worked well with English text but it got broken when the tweet contained non-ASCII characters. This solution avoids that problem:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

// Return hyperlinked tweet text from json_decoded status object:
function MakeStatusLinks($status) 
{$TextLength=mb_strlen($status['text']); // Number of UTF-8 characters in plain tweet.
 for ($i=0;$i<$TextLength;$i++)
 {$ch=mb_substr($status['text'],$i,1); if ($ch<>"\n") $ChAr[]=$ch; else $ChAr[]="\n<br/>"; // Keep new lines in HTML tweet.
 }
if (isset($status['entities']['user_mentions']))
 foreach ($status['entities']['user_mentions'] as $entity)
 {$ChAr[$entity['indices'][0]] = "<a href='https://twitter.com/".$entity['screen_name']."'>".$ChAr[$entity['indices'][0]];
  $ChAr[$entity['indices'][1]-1].="</a>";
 }
if (isset($status['entities']['hashtags']))
 foreach ($status['entities']['hashtags'] as $entity)
 {$ChAr[$entity['indices'][0]] = "<a href='https://twitter.com/search?q=%23".$entity['text']."'>".$ChAr[$entity['indices'][0]];
  $ChAr[$entity['indices'][1]-1] .= "</a>";
 }
if (isset($status['entities']['urls']))
 foreach ($status['entities']['urls'] as $entity)
 {$ChAr[$entity['indices'][0]] = "<a href='".$entity['expanded_url']."'>".$entity['display_url']."</a>";
  for ($i=$entity['indices'][0]+1;$i<$entity['indices'][1];$i++) $ChAr[$i]='';
 }
if (isset($status['entities']['media']))
 foreach ($status['entities']['media'] as $entity)
 {$ChAr[$entity['indices'][0]] = "<a href='".$entity['expanded_url']."'>".$entity['display_url']."</a>";
  for ($i=$entity['indices'][0]+1;$i<$entity['indices'][1];$i++) $ChAr[$i]='';
 }
return implode('', $ChAr); // HTML tweet.
}
```

Comment: Good catch.  I encountered this issue also.  I updated my answer with the solution I am using.  It splits the string properly when multibyte characters are involved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated answer that works with Twitter's new Extended Mode. It combines the answer by @vita10gy and the comment by @Hugo (to make it utf8 compatible), with a few minor tweaks to work with the new api values.

```
function utf8_substr_replace($original, $replacement, $position, $length) {
    $startString = mb_substr($original, 0, $position, "UTF-8");
    $endString = mb_substr($original, $position + $length, mb_strlen($original), "UTF-8");
    $out = $startString . $replacement . $endString;
    return $out;
}

function json_tweet_text_to_HTML($tweet, $links=true, $users=true, $hashtags=true) {
    // Media urls can show up on the end of the full_text tweet, but twitter doesn't index that url. 
    // The display_text_range indexes show the actual tweet text length.
    // Cut the string off at the end to get rid of this unindexed url.
    $return = mb_substr($tweet->full_text, $tweet->display_text_range[0],$tweet->display_text_range[1]);
    $entities = array();

    if($links && is_array($tweet->entities->urls))
    {
        foreach($tweet->entities->urls as $e)
        {
            $temp["start"] = $e->indices[0];
            $temp["end"] = $e->indices[1];
            $temp["replacement"] = " <a href='".$e->expanded_url."' target='_blank'>".$e->display_url."</a>";
            $entities[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    if($users && is_array($tweet->entities->user_mentions))
    {
        foreach($tweet->entities->user_mentions as $e)
        {
            $temp["start"] = $e->indices[0];
            $temp["end"] = $e->indices[1];
            $temp["replacement"] = " <a href='https://twitter.com/".$e->screen_name."' target='_blank'>@".$e->screen_name."</a>";
            $entities[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    if($hashtags && is_array($tweet->entities->hashtags))
    {
        foreach($tweet->entities->hashtags as $e)
        {
            $temp["start"] = $e->indices[0];
            $temp["end"] = $e->indices[1];
            $temp["replacement"] = " <a href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/".$e->text."?src=hash' target='_blank'>#".$e->text."</a>";
            $entities[] = $temp;
        }
    }

    usort($entities, function($a,$b){return($b["start"]-$a["start"]);});


    foreach($entities as $item)
    {
        $return =  utf8_substr_replace($return, $item["replacement"], $item["start"], $item["end"] - $item["start"]);
    }

    return($return);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript version (using jQuery) of [vita10gy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3461892/vita10gy)'s solution

```
function tweetTextToHtml(tweet, links, users, hashtags) {

    if (typeof(links)==='undefined') { links = true; }
    if (typeof(users)==='undefined') { users = true; }
    if (typeof(hashtags)==='undefined') { hashtags = true; }

    var returnStr = tweet.text;
    var entitiesArray = [];

    if(links && tweet.entities.urls.length > 0) {
        jQuery.each(tweet.entities.urls, function() {
            var temp1 = {};
            temp1.start = this.indices[0];
            temp1.end = this.indices[1];
            temp1.replacement = '<a href="' + this.expanded_url + '" target="_blank">' + this.display_url + '</a>';
            entitiesArray.push(temp1);
        });
    }

    if(users && tweet.entities.user_mentions.length > 0) {
        jQuery.each(tweet.entities.user_mentions, function() {
            var temp2 = {};
            temp2.start = this.indices[0];
            temp2.end = this.indices[1];
            temp2.replacement = '<a href="https://twitter.com/' + this.screen_name + '" target="_blank">@' + this.screen_name + '</a>';
            entitiesArray.push(temp2);
        });
    }

    if(hashtags && tweet.entities.hashtags.length > 0) {
        jQuery.each(tweet.entities.hashtags, function() {
            var temp3 = {};
            temp3.start = this.indices[0];
            temp3.end = this.indices[1];
            temp3.replacement = '<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + this.text + '?src=hash" target="_blank">#' + this.text + '</a>';
            entitiesArray.push(temp3);
        });
    }

    entitiesArray.sort(function(a, b) {return b.start - a.start;});

    jQuery.each(entitiesArray, function() {
        returnStr = substrReplace(returnStr, this.replacement, this.start, this.end - this.start);
    });

    return returnStr;
}
```

You can then use this function like so ...

```
for(var i in tweetsJsonObj) {
    var tweet = tweetsJsonObj[i];
    var htmlTweetText = tweetTextToHtml(tweet);

    // Do something with the formatted tweet here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding vita10gy's helpful `json_tweet_text_to_HTML()`, I found a tweet that it could not format correctly: 626125868247552000.

This tweet has a nonbreaking space in it. My solution was to replace the first line of the function with the following:

```
$return = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", ' ', $tweet->text);
```

Performing a `str_replace()` on `&nbsp;` is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275380/does-html-entity-decode-replaces-nbsp-also-if-not-how-to-replace-it).