# How to get the indented text from the Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using the followin cURL request to get all tweets from an account:

```php
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?screen_name=heregoestheaccount&tweet_mode=extended&count=50';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$twitter->setGetfield($getfield);
$twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod);
$response = $twitter->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0));
$tweets = json_decode($response, true);
```

I'm now getting the following array:

```php
array (size=26)
  'created_at' => string 'Fri Sep 25 12:05:51 +0000 2020' (length=30)
  'id' => int 1309464126494846976
  'id_str' => string '1309464126494846976' (length=19)
  'full_text' => string '[ #Esports ]

On Sunday 27.09.2020 at 1 p.m. the First Division Qualifier for the Rainbow Six: Siege Fall Season 2020 will start! Our team will fight for its slot in the first division.

We wish all the best for their first competition in the noetic team!

#noeticBLAST  (length=302)
  'truncated' => boolean false
  'display_text_range' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 272
  'entities' => 
...
```

My problem is that, when rendering the `full_text` of the tweet, the text does not follow the original indentation, since it renders like this.
[image: 1]

How to display the original indentation of the tweet?

**EDIT:** I have the following HTML to display the text:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
    <p>
        <?= $tweet['full_text']; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:** according to @Pascal comment, I added `<pre>` tag in my `<p>`.

Here's what is displayed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVtU6.png)

But that's not what I want, since I don't want the user to have to scroll to see the text.

Comment: put it in pre tag html like this  `<pre>...</pre>` and make some css

Comment: Can you please tell me at which place should I put it, following the edit?

Comment: inside your p tag like `<p><pre><?= $tweet['full_text']; ?></pre></p>`

Comment: Please check what I added to the post :)

Comment: I know what you want, for get things done you should create your custom format text to do this job done. This is one post that may interrest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533214/php-how-to-use-the-twitter-apis-data-to-convert-urls-mentions-and-hastags-in

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this. It's ugly, but it works:

```php
<?=str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br/>", $tweet['full_text']); ?></p>
```