# Unable to remove space in the plaintext with the use of simplehtmldom

Tags: php, preg-replace, trim, simple-html-dom

I am using simplehtmldom to get some website data with this

```
$data = array();
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/'.$value, false, $context);
foreach($details as $value){

   $dataele = array();

    foreach($html->find('*[class=style11]') as $element){

      $houseinfo = trim($element->plaintext, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");
      echo $houseinfo;
      echo '<br>';
      array_push($dataele, $houseinfo);

    }   
}
```

but I found that there're some `&nbsp;` when I insert these data into database.
I have tried different methods but it can't really remove the `&nbsp;` html tag. The methods I have tried:

```
$houseinfo = trim($element->plaintext, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");
$dataele[1] = html_entity_decode($dataele[1]);
$dataele[1] = str_replace("&nbsp;", "_", $dataele[1]);
$houseinfo = filter_var($houseinfo, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dataele[1] = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i", "", $dataele[1]);
```

Comment: `Note:
You might wonder why trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;')); doesn't reduce the string to an empty string, that's because the '&nbsp;' entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is stripped by trim()) but ASCII code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 encoding.`

Comment: @Class so could you tell me how can i make it works please ?

Comment: If you echo out the HTML with a method such as `urlencode` you'll be able to see what characters are hidden, if any, and hence why your stuff isn't being replaced..

Comment: [Does html_entity_decode replaces &nbsp; also? If not how to replace it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6275467/1700963)

Comment: @h2ooooooo thank you very much, I have found where the problem is. I just found that thats `&nbsp` , not `&nbsp;` ...

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help.

```
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', htmlspecialchars_decode($element->plaintext)); 
            $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-_!@#:$%^&*\/()+={}<>?;, \-]/', '', $string);
            $string = preg_replace('/-+/', ' ', $string);
    echo $string;
```