# How to check if "&nbsp;" exist?

Tags: php, string, utf-8

When I print a variable, I get a blank result and when I inspect the element I see that `&nbsp;`.

I tried to check if the variables is empty or equals this value:

```
ir( empty($string) || $string == "&nbsp;" || strpos($string, "&nbsp;") || $string == " "){
    //Do Something.
}
```

But the code inside that condition is not executed.

When I `var_dump($string)`, I get:

```
string(2) " "
```

What should I do to check if the variable equals or contain that?

Comment: I would suggest to check for null or empty string using trim(): `(!isset($string) || trim($string) === '')`

Comment: what is `ir` ??

Comment: must be a typo: `if`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, The problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, People get tripped up on this move all the time...

```
strpos($string, "&nbsp;")
```

If `&nbsp;` is at the start of your string, then the evaluated result is `0` ("offset position") AND `0` is loosely compared to `false` in the way that you have crafted your conditional expression.

You need to explicitly check for `false` (strict check) from `strpos()` like this:

```
if (empty($string) || strpos($string, "&nbsp;") !== false || $string == " ") {
    //Do Something.
}
```

### However, that is NOT your actual issue because...

You have a multibyte space evidenced by when you "highlight" the character with your cursor -- it only has a character length of one, but when you call `var_dump()` there is a byte count of `2`.

`trim()` can't help you.  `ctype_space()` can't help you.  You need something that is multibyte aware.

To allow the most inclusive match, I'll employ a regular expression that will search for all whitespace characters, invisible control characters, and unused code points.

```
if (empty($string) || preg_match("/^[\pZ\pC]+$/u", $string)) {
```

This will check if the string is truly empty or is entirely composed of one or more of the aforementioned characters.

Here's a little demo: https://3v4l.org/u7eoK

(I don't really think this is a `&nbsp;` issue, so I am leaving that out of my solution.)

Scroll down this resource: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: I have just seen the answer, I didn't get a notification

Answer (score 1):

The solution, If the utf-8 is used:

```
$a = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", '', $a);
```

If ASCII :

```
$a = str_replace("\xA0", '', $a);
```

Then the $a is empty now and you could check it using `if(empty($a))`

The answer exists here: [Does html_entity_decode replaces &nbsp; also? If not how to replace it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275380/does-html-entity-decode-replaces-nbsp-also-if-not-how-to-replace-it)

Comment: Typically `empty()` or `isset()` is called _before_ any other processes are run on the variable.  This is done to avoid generating `Notices` in the event that a SUPERGLOBAL key is not declared.

Comment: You mean that both can't be used to check the last result, Or I miss understood you?