# unable to split a string that is parsed from a webpage?

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing, split

Here I am parsing a webpage and getting the 'name' field from that webpage. Here is the code that does the parsing:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table) {
    if($table->getAttribute('class')=='dataTable'){
        foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
            if(isset($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue)){
                $out[$i]['name'] = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the webpage I am parsing I have the nodevalue for `name` in the form of 'Mark&nbspSmith'. So when I get the result I have 'name' value as 'Mark Smith' in IDE and 'Mark┬áSmith' in command promt.

Now I want to split the 'name' string in such a way so that I get firstname('Mark') and lastname('smith') separately.

I tried:

```
explode("┬á", $out[$i]['name']) as well as
explode(" " , $out[$i]['name'])
```

But nothing seems to work for me. Help me to split the string as firstname and lastname?

Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: You have some strange convention of closing braces.

Comment: i purposefully put the closing braces bcoz the code is not completed fully.. i 've some other operations being performed which is not relevent to this topic..so omitted it.. @PeeHaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1518659 here try this, to fix the issue just replace the `&nbsp;` with a space before passing to DOMDocument, I also added the split of firstname last name :) hope it helps.

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); //Required if your outputting, as the description contains utf-8 characters
//Load the source (input)
$html_source = file_get_contents('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=AOS');
$html_source = str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',$html_source);

//Dom document
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
@$dom->loadHTML($html_source);

$out =array();
$i=0;
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table) {
    if($table->getAttribute('class')=='dataTable'){

        foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
            if(isset($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue)){

                $out[$i]['fullname'] = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;

                $name = explode(' ',$out[$i]['fullname']);
                $out[$i]['first_name'] = $name[0];
                $out[$i]['last_name'] = $name[1];

                if(!isset($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2)->nodeValue)){

                    foreach ($out as $key=>$value){
                        if($value['fullname'] == $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue &&
                        !is_numeric(substr($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->nodeValue,0,1)) && 
                        $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->nodeValue != "--" ){
                            $out[$key]['description']= $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->nodeValue;
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    if(!isset($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2)->nodeValue)){continue;}
                    if(isset($tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(3)->nodeValue)){
                        $out[$i]['age']= $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->nodeValue;
                        $out[$i]['since']= $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2)->nodeValue;
                        $out[$i]['position']= $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(3)->nodeValue;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Clean up
$return = array();
foreach ($out as $key=>$row){
    if(isset($row['fullname']) && isset($row['age']) && isset($row['since']) && isset($row['position']) && isset($row['description'])){
        $return[$key] = $out[$key];
    }
}


print_r($return);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Paul Jones
            [first_name] => Paul
            [last_name] => Jones
            [age] => 63
            [since] => 2011
            [position] => Chairman of the Board, Chief Executive Officer
            [description] => Mr. Paul W. Jones serves as the Chairman of the Board, Chief Executive Officer of A. O. Smith Corp. He has been a director of company since 2004. He is a member of the Investment Policy Committee of the Board. He was elected chairman of the board, president and chief executive officer effective December 31, 2005. He was president and chief operating officer from 2004 to 2005. Prior to joining the company, he was chairman and chief executive officer of U.S. Can Company, Inc. from 1998 to 2002. He previously was president and chief executive officer of Greenfield Industries, Inc. from 1993 to 1998 and president from 1989 to 1992. Mr. Jones has been a director of Federal Signal Corporation since 1998, where he chairs the Nominating and Governance Committee and is a member of the Compensation and Benefits Committee and the Executive Committee, and Integrys Energy Group, Inc. since 2011, where he is a member of the Compensation and Financial Committees. He was also a director of Bucyrus International, Inc. from 2006 until its acquisition by Caterpillar, Inc. in 2011, and chaired the Compensation Committee.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => Ajita Rajendra
            [first_name] => Ajita
            [last_name] => Rajendra
            [age] => 60
            [since] => 2011
            [position] => President, Chief Operating Officer, Director
            [description] => Mr. Ajita G. Rajendra serves as the President, Chief Operating Officer and Director of A. O. Smith Corp. He was elected a director of company in December 2011, based on the recommendation of the Nominating and Governance Committee, following his election as President and Chief Operating Officer in September 2011. Mr. Rajendra joined the company as President of A. O. Smith Water Products Company in 2005, and was named Executive Vice President of the company in 2006. Prior to joining the company, Mr. Rajendra was Senior Vice President at Kennametal, Inc., a manufacturer of cutting tools, from 1998 to 2004. Mr. Rajendra also serves on the board of Donaldson Company, Inc., where he is a member of the Audit Committee and Human Resources Committee. Further, Mr. Rajendra was a director of Industrial Distribution Group, Inc. from 2007 until its acquisition by Eiger Holdco, LLC in 2008.
        )
        ...
        ...
*/
?>
```

Comment: THANKS @Lawrece Cherone ..  that one worked like a charm.. +1

Comment: Na sorry no offense :), your always welcome to ask your questions here @ SO.

Comment: Now I am trying to insert the datas got from the result array in to mysql database. I'm wondering if its possible to insert approximately 1000 rows at a time via a query other than appending each value on the end of an mile long string and then executing it.

Comment: If you use PDO then you can easily create a model to handle your database input, your need to open a new question with the code you have so far.

Comment: Also in the result array, in the description field few details are in invalide format.. for eg. the original description contains (“Bemis”) in the webpage but it is displayed as (├ó┬Ç┬£Bemis├ó┬Ç┬¥) in the parsed result. check the url's page source. what possibily 
could be the reason.. how to resolve it.?
I also tried
$html_source = str_replace('“','"',$html_source);
$html_source = str_replace('”','"',$html_source);
but couldn't able to get it right.

Comment: @user1518659 you should use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` if your going to output to the browser, also if your going to store result in a database the charset also needs tobe utf-8 as there are utf-8 characters in the description. I previously added the header to an edit perhaps you missed it.

Comment: ya.. i noted it and also tried but that doesn't seem to be utf-8 charset.. and the result is still the same.. no changes..still getting (├ó┬Ç┬£Bemis├ó┬Ç┬¥).  try searching 'Bemis' in the pagesource and look for (“Bemis”) and tell me which charset to use..i ve a bad knowledge about it..

Answer (score 3):

Have a try to fix the &nbsp issue:

`explode(chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0), $str)`

> The non-breaking space exist in UTF-8 of two bytes: 0xC2 and 0xA0.

Ref - [PHP Parsing Problem - &nbsp; and Â](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515117/php-parsing-problem-nbsp-and-%C3%82)

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The non-breaking space character entity you have there is broken. It should be `&nbsp;`. Note the semicolon.

To answer your question you can simply do:

```
var_dump(explode('&nbsp', $out[$i]['name']));
```

Or if the entity is fixed:

```
var_dump(explode('&nbsp;', $out[$i]['name']));
```

Comment: still not able to get it.. now what I am trying is 
$out[$i]['name'] = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $chars = explode('&nbsp', $out[$i]['name']);
    $out[$i]['f_name'] = $chars[0];
    $out[$i]['l_name'] = $chars[1];

and the result I am getting is

[name] => Gene Wulf
            [f_name] => Gene Wulf
            [l_name] => 

It is not splitting.

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/byfC8W). So either the name you have given as an example in your code isn't the real string or there is something else wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
<?php

$a = preg_split( "/[\s]|[&nbsp;]|[┬á]/", $out[$i]['name'] ); //$a is an array with keys: Mark, Smith
```

`explode()` only allows one delimiter to split the string/array while `preg_split()` is used for a variety of delimiters

Comment: That is almost perfect but php doesn't recognize '┬'. when i tried to inclue '┬' it simply includes [-á] instead of [┬á]. how to solve this?

Comment: 'Mark┬áSmith' is getting splitted as 'Mark┬' and 'Smith' but 'Gene┬áWulf' is getting splitted as 'Ge' and 'e┬' and also 'Mathias┬áSandoval' as 'Mathia' and '┬' ..  not the expected result as you know.. where we are missing?