# parsing html containing &nbsp; (non-breaking space)

Tags: r, stringr

I am using `rvest` to parse a website. I'm hitting a wall with these little non-breaking spaces. How does one remove the whitespace that is created by the `&nbsp;` element in a parsed html document?

```
library("rvest")
library("stringr")  

minimal <- html("<!doctype html><title>blah</title> <p>&nbsp;foo")

bodytext <- minimal %>%
  html_node("body") %>% 
  html_text
```

Now I have extracted the body text:

```
bodytext
[1] " foo"
```

However, I can't remove that pesky bit of whitespace!

```
str_trim(bodytext)

gsub(pattern = " ", "", bodytext)
```

Answer (score 11):

jdharrison answered:

```
gsub("\\W", "", bodytext)
```

and, that will work but you can use:

```
gsub("[[:space:]]", "", bodytext)
```

which will remove all `Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters`. It's a very readable alternative to other, cryptic regex classes.

Comment: Unfortunately that latter solution, however readable, doesn't work.  The problem seems to involve encoding (see my comment to @MrFlick)

Comment: However, the `\\W` technique DOES work! So apparently, whatever that space is encoded as in my locale, it ISN'T a word!

Comment: unchecked because while that does work, removing nonword characters is too extreme for my application, and I still really want to know how to match this space!

Answer (score 11):

I have run into the same problem, and have settled on the simple substitution of

```
gsub(intToUtf8(160),'',bodytext)
```

(Edited to correct case.)

Answer (score 3):

The `&nbsp` stands for "non-breaking space" which, in the unicode space, has it's own distinct character from a "regular" space (ie `" "`). Compare

```
charToRaw(" foo")
# [1] 20 66 6f 6f
charToRaw(bodytext)
# [1] c2 a0 66 6f 6f
```

So you'd want to use one of the special character classes for white space. You can remove all white spaces with

```
gsub("\\s", "", bodytext)
```

On Windows, I needed to make sure the encoding of the string was set properly

```
Encoding(bodytext) <- "UTF-8"
gsub("\\s", "", bodytext)
```

Comment: that `charToRaw` function is wonderful! OK so I'd actually tried something similar. As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515117/php-parsing-problem-nbsp-and-%C3%82), the `&nbsp;` gets interpreted as "Â" and " ". The trouble is that while I could match the "Â" with a regex, I cannot do so with the space.  Your encoding trick didn't help. Forgive me for not reproducing this work here; I could not get the "Â" to replicate in my example

Comment: You'll see the "Â" if you don't have the encoding properly set on the variable. What do you get if you do `Encoding(bodytext)`? You can also probably safely set it to "latin1"

Comment: `Encoding(bodytext)` returns `UTF-8`, yet what appears as a blank space cannot be matched by any expression that targets spaces, neither `\\s` nor `[:space:]`

Comment: You should amend your question to include the results of `sessionInfo()` which should have R version and OS version. So you're saying you don't see the "Â", you see a space but `\\s` doesn't match it? And you're testing on the example in your original post? And you get the same `charToRaw()` values as I do?

Answer (score 3):

Posting this since I think it's the most robust approach.

I scraped a Wikipedia page and got this in my output (not sure if it'll copy-paste properly):

```
x <- " California"
```

And `gsub("\\s", "", x)` didn't change anything, which raised the flag that something fishy is going on.

To investigate, I did:

```
dput(charToRaw(strsplit(x, "")[[1]][1]))
# as.raw(c(0xc2, 0xa0))
```

To figure out how exactly that character is stored/recognized in memory.

With this in hand, we can use `gsub` a bit more robustly than in the other solutions:

```
gsub(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xc2, 0xa0))), "", x)
# [1] "California"
```

(@MrFlick's suggestion to set the encoding didn't work for me, and it's not clear where @shabbychef got the input `160` for `intToUtf8`; this approach can be generalized to other similar situations)

Answer (score 0):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.  Also I am not able to reproduce your encoding problems, the following correctly substitutes the space regardless of encoding on my machine.  (It is the same solution as `[[:space:]]` though, so likely has the same issue for you)

```
re_substitutes(bodytext, rex(spaces), "", global = TRUE)

#> [1] "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove `&nbsp;` spaces at the beginning and end of strings with `mystring %>% stringr::str_trim()`.