# Convert latin1 characters on a UTF8 table into UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Only today I realized that I was missing this in my PHP scripts:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

All my tables are InnoDB, collation "utf8_unicode_ci", and all my VARCHAR columns are "utf8_unicode_ci" as well. I have `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` on my PHP scripts, and all my PHP files are encoded as UTF-8.

So, until now, every time I "INSERT" something with diacritics, example:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`="Jáuò Iñe"');
```

The 'name' contents would be, in this case: `JÃ¡uÃ² IÃ±e`.

Since I fixed the charset between PHP and MySQL, new INSERTs are now storing correctly. However, I want to fix all the older rows that are "messed" at the moment. I tried many things already, but it always breaks the strings on the first "illegal" character. Here is my current code:

```
$m = mysql_real_escape_string('¿<?php echo "¬<b>\'PHP &aacute; (á)ţăriîş </b>"; ?> ă-ţi abcdd;//;ñç´พดแทฝใจคçăâξβψδπλξξςαยนñ ;');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`="'.$m.'"');
mysql_set_charset('latin1');
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `table` SET `name`="'.$m.'"');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$result = mysql_iquery('SELECT * FROM `table`');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $message = $row['name'];
    $message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-8');
    //$message = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $message);
    mysql_iquery('UPDATE `table` SET `name`="'.mysql_real_escape_string($message).'" WHERE `a1`="'.$row['a1'].'"');
}
```

It "UPDATE"s with the expected characters, except that the string gets truncated after the character "ă". I mean, that character and following chars are not included on the string.

Also, testing with the "iconv()" (that is commented on the code) does the same, even with //IGNORE and //TRANSLIT

I also tested several charsets, between ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15.

Comment: Your `JÃ¡uÃ² IÃ±e` should have been `Jáuò Iñe`, correct?  The 2-step ALTER _may_ be appropriate (and relatively simple).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71960959/1766831

Comment: Rick - I appreciate your help, but this question was asked in 2012, I got an answer on the same day that saved my day (and still grateful for it!), you edited my question in 2020, and 2 years later you're suggesting an answer. That's very funny :D :-) -- good day to you, enjoy your day!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

From what you describe, it seems you have UTF-8 data that was originally stored as Latin-1 and then not converted correctly to UTF-8. The data is recoverable; you'll need a MySQL function like

```
convert(cast(convert(name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```

It's possible that you may need to omit the inner conversion, depending on how the data was altered during the encoding conversion.

Comment: WOW you saved my day! I never used those functions, used now on an UPDATE and it worked. Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: Thanks for this! I've build a small php script that loops through all columns in each table. Did the trick :)

Comment: THANKS A LOT ABS!!!!! A lot of related SO questions but only this one contained the function to convert correctly to UTF-8

Comment: your answer helped for my fixes. Thanks

Comment: After more than 5 years, this great answer saved me from lot of heart aches. you are simply brilliant. However, I have a question: if there are many columns to convert, will a wildcard work instead of name?

Comment: I wrote [a little Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/scotchi/0823048d923ab506db858dd5e90a5dc9) to do this for all Wordpress tables.

Comment: Caution:  There are many different causes of messed up utf8.  That expression works for one case.  Here is a list of cases that I have identified:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the exact same with php?

Comment: This give me some problem with "new" data, already stored in utf8.

Comment: It's still useful in 2021. Thanks. If someone needs to run the Ruby script in Rails (as rake task) simply omit the creation of the client replace `client.query` with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and it should work.

Comment: In 2022 after updating from really old debian and basically websites which were created using php5, this was the most helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: **CAUTION** don't run the above function on data that is *already* in UTF8. It will **nuke** everything after the first already-UTF8 character.  You can witness this by running it over the same field twice.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed an issue I was having.

Comment: See https://jonisalonen.com/2012/fixing-doubly-utf-8-encoded-text-in-mysql/ for more information and a solution for not changing singly and doubly encoded text.

Answer (score 35):

After I searched about an hour or two for this answer, I needed to migrate an old tt_news db from typo into a new typo3 version. I  tried to convert the charset in the export file and import it back already, but didn't get it working.

Then I tried the answer above from ABS and started an update on the table:

```
UPDATE tt_news SET 
    title=convert(cast(convert(title using  latin1) as binary) using utf8), 
    short=convert(cast(convert(short using  latin1) as binary) using utf8), 
    bodytext=convert(cast(convert(bodytext using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
WHERE 1
```

You can also convert imagecaption, imagealttext, imagetitletext and keywords if needed.
Hope this will help somebody migrating tt_news to new typo3 version.

Comment: I didn't get ABS' answer until I reached yours.

Comment: Indeed, ABS' answer is the "key" to the answer.  Marcel's answer uses that "key" in a complete example.  Upvote both!

Comment: Upvoted both, crucial query for any cross-database exports/imports. Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

the way is better way
use connection tow you database normal

then use this code to make what you need
you must make your page encoding utf-8 by meta in header cod html (dont forget this)

then use this code

```
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM shops');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ 
    $name= iconv("windows-1256", "UTF-8", $row['name']);

   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
   mysql_query("update   `shops` SET `name`='".$name."'  where ID='$row[ID]'  ");
    }
```

Comment: It's not better, and your way breaks the first time a name contains an apostrophe. Also, why do you perform "SET NAMES" for every single row?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using 'utf8mb4' instead of 'utf8', since utf8 cannot store some chinese characters and emojis.

Comment: [True](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434), but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

to convert different Encoding standards like latin1 UTF8  UTF8

just use ('name' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS) after the field name

"Select name collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS from person_Table"