# PHP charset conversion

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I had previously encoded MySQL data in latin1. Now, I've converted it to UTF-8 in MySQL but the data is still saved in latin1.
UTF-8 data that was originally stored as Latin-1 has not converted correctly to UTF-8.
I need a work around in PHP, so that when I get data from the database using a query, it should be converted into UTF-8.

I found a solution to convert the database using a MySQL function, which is really helpful...
[MySQL - Convert latin1 characters on a UTF8 table into UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407834/mysql-convert-latin1-characters-on-a-utf8-table-into-utf8)

But my scenario is, I need to do this in PHP.

Comment: Have you tried [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)?

Comment: Or just [`utf8_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: Beside from other changes that might being required, you'll have to issue `SET names UTF8` as the first command after connecting to mysql. This is important!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP functions utf8_encode (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php) and utf8_decode (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php)

Then you have to loop in your SQL tables to replace values with sanitized ones

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from table");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    //Then update row with new name
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET col_name = '" . utf8_decode($result["col_name"]) ."' WHERE id = " . $result["id"]);

  }
?>
```