# mysqldump default-character-set does not affect on enum character set

Tags: enums, mysql

I have a table that its default character set is latin1 but it contains the utf-8 values as rows. I have a enum column in this table that contains utf-8 as its items. While dumping by setting `--default-character-set='latin1'` its data correctly converted and are readable but enum values in definition does not convert and they are not readable:

[image]

MySQL version: 5.1

OS: RHEL 6.3

I can't alter table, It's in progress.

Any solution?

Comment: please read thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049903/converting-mysql-table-with-incorrectly-encoded-data-to-utf-8 it might help ..

Comment: I am not talking about data, I mean the values of definition an enum column.

Comment: How do you dump the db?

Comment: @Phate01 mysqldump --default-char-set=utf8 --opt -uroot -p dbname tablename > dump.sql

Comment: default-character-set