# MySQL convert charset issue

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I have an application which runs on PHP 5 and accesses and stores a MySQL database using the **mysqli** extension. The database contains numerous tables with the encoding **UTF-8** (collation **utf8_swedish_ci**).

Unfortunately, it seems that the mysqli connection was configured to encode everything using ISO-8859-1,which means that I've got **UTF-8** tables containing **latin1** data. I am trying to repair this now, by shifting over everything to UTF-8 (as it should be!)

Is there a built-in way of handling this?  If there isn't, how would you recommend I approach this issue?

---

**Edit:** A sample of what the data looks like while browsing through it all using PHPMyAdmin:

`handelÃ«` (should be `handelë`)

`âˆšskal` (should be `√skal`)

Also, the data is output correctly in the HTML document, as long as I use the output encoding  UTF-8, but maintain the mysqli connection charset as latin1. It's all rather confusing,.

Very grateful for your help!

Comment: try `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: How would I convert over the data without corrupting everything?

Comment: If it did happen to corrupt everything, you can do a `REPAIR` on the tables. (I haven't worked much with charsets, but I'm just giving my 2 cents)

Comment: Create I backup (for security) before and after that do this: `ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: Also do it for tables: `ALTER TABLE db_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: Use [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) to let both ends know they should use UTF-8. As far as converting a database, I am not sure what the recommend way of doing that is.

Comment: My own two cents: *if* the sql client is configured to *return* data as Latin1, and the table encode data as UTF8, shouldn't the conversion be transparently done? I understand your table column to be *declared* as UTF8, but are you 100% sure the actual data in your table are really UTF8?

Comment: No, the data in the table is encoded using latin1.  I need to find out a way to easily convert the data to UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right! So this is what must have happened:

user interface (UTF-8) → controller (UTF-8) → model (ISO-8859-1) → Database (UTF-8, but it receives ISO-8859-1)

So the fields were configured to use the UTF-8 encoding, but they receive ISO-8859-1 encoded data. I wanted to convert the incorrectly encoded data to UTF-8.

Since the data was in fact ISO-8559-1 encoded, I resolved my problem with the following little MySQL "hack":

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = convert(cast(convert(`column` using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```

Courtesy [ABS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407998/690920) on StackOverflow.

Thank you for your time looking into my problem, guys! :)