# How can I apply utf8_encode() or similar to all VARCHARs on a database? (PHP / MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

Suddenly I have to work with this database filled with lots of data and the whole system is full of encoding problems. Some tables are Latin1, others UTF8, mixed collations, and utf8_encode() PHP conversions all spread randomly throughout the files. It's a nightmare, and I'm trying to solve it.

Ok, I've created a PHP script to update the charset and collation of the whole schmere.

```
<?php
    include("vars.php");
    $servername = DB_HOST;
    $username = DB_USER;
    $password = DB_PASS;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;
    $charset = "utf8";
    $collation = "utf8_general_ci";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME,'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ".$charset." COLLATE ".$collation.";') 
            AS MYSQL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $conn->prepare($row[0])->execute();
            echo $row[0] . " EXECUTED </br>";
        }
        echo "FINISHED.";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

The problem here is that lots of varchars are stored like this: "OBRAGEN ENGENHARIA E CONSTRUÃ‡Ã•ES LTDA", and the previous developer used utf8_encode() on multiple files because of that. In order to achieve a standard, I've removed all utf8_encode() conversions in order to rely only on the database. How can I "utf8_encodely" convert ALL varchars on the database? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `utf8_encode()`.

Use `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')`.  Then all text from MySQL will come at you as utf8.  That is whether it is in a column that is `CHARACTER SET latin1` or whatever.  MySQL does the conversion.

Then make sure your client code thinks *only* utf8.

And any display mechanism uses utf8.  For example, HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

A quick check of what is in the tables...  Find some accented character, and do

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

It will show 1-byte (2 hex) for a `CHARACTER SET latin1` column, or 2-byte (4 hex) for utf8.

`Ã‡Ã•` is Mojibake for `ÇÕ`.  It probably means that ...

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

If you find that a table has incorrectly stored data, we can look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manually identify the table fields which has the utf8 encoded content in latin1 collation tables. Then update those fields like @ABS method and provided example by @Marcel Grolms in following question.

[MySQL - Convert latin1 characters on a UTF8 table into UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407834/mysql-convert-latin1-characters-on-a-utf8-table-into-utf8)