# Change MySQL encoding (regarding hex codes?), such as <fc> to ü

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, phpmyadmin, ascii

I am not sure how my error is termed, but I think my data show [hex codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) rather than the actual foreign characters.

To be more precise, I have a MySQL database with data like:

- `G<e9>rard` instead of `Gérard`, or
- `M<fc>nster` instead of `Münster`.

Apparently my columns have an `utf8_unicode_ci`-encoding (according to *phpMyAdmin*).

Now I wish to convert strings like `<e9>` into `é`, either directly in the MySQL-database, or in PHP when the output is being shown.

Apparently others were able to use [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051176/14308375) to convert their MySQL-table successfully;

```
UPDATE db_name SET 
    column1=convert(cast(convert(column1 using latin1) as binary) using utf8), 
    column2=convert(cast(convert(column2 using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```

However, this doesn't change anything in my case.

So how can I achieve the conversion?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear if you mean your data `G<e9>rard` has a single byte E9 as the second byte, or does it literally have four printable characters `<e9>`? That's going to be much trickier to convert using SQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I fear these are four printable characters. Is it "tricky", or is it "impossible"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would fix this if the special characters are actually sequences of four characters.

First, make sure the table is all converted to utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Use the [REPLACE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to fix each character one by one.

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
  column1 = REPLACE(column1, '<e9>', 'é'),
  column2 = REPLACE(column2, '<e9>', 'é');
```

Be careful if you're editing this SQL query by copy & paste. Make sure you fix `column2` in both the left side and right side of the `=`. Otherwise if you forget one, you could copy the content of column1 into column2, and lose the old content of column2.

Once you're done with `é`, then do a similar statement for `ü`:

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
  column1 = REPLACE(column1, '<fc>', 'ü'),
  column2 = REPLACE(column2, '<fc>', 'ü');
```

Gradually you will clean up all these hex sequences. You can search the table to see if you have any remaining:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1, '<[[:xdigit:]]{2}>') FROM mytable 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '<[[:xdigit:]]{2}>');
```

(MySQL 8.0 is required for [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr))

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! It worked well; even with the collation `utf8_unicode_ci`.