# data in database becomes wrong when fetching after using charset=utf8 in PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo, utf-8

I have a database which some of its table columns was in `latin1_swedish_ci`, I used PDO connection without `charset=utf8` and the data returned well with only using `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');`, then I have created some new table columns with utf8 encoding and when fetching the data it is returned like this `?????`, with some search I found that I have to use PDO connection with `charset=utf8`, but adding the last one cause new tables work well, but old tables work wrong, I have used `utf8_encoding` but nothing happened, what I have to do now, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should [convert all your db data/tables/columns to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407834/convert-latin1-characters-on-a-utf8-table-into-utf8) and then make sure you're using [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: I have converted all database tables to UTF8, also I have now utf8 in tables, columns , connection and header content, now my problem is I have a data in latin and utf8 in my database and want to return it correctly, but latin data returned wrong Ø§Ù„Ø¯Ù…Ø§Ù…

Comment: need any solution except using that CONVERT(CAST(t1.`name` as BINARY) USING utf8) as name