# MySQL : Weird Characters

Tags: mysql

Data was coming with weird characters like

```
 FS â€“ Bronze
 FS â€“ Gold
 FS â€“ Silver
 FS â€“ Wood
 FS Ã¢â‚¬â€œ Bronze
 FS Ã¢â‚¬â€œ Gold
 FS Ã¢â‚¬â€œ Silver
 FSâ€“ Wood
 FSÃ¢â‚¬â€œ Wood
```

Usually the data should look like

```
  FS– Wood
  FS– Silver
```

Not sure why Hyphen was replaced with weird characters. Please help to change with a SQL query.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us the character set encoding of the column in your table and of the software you're using to render this data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/a-showing-on-page-instead-of

Comment: Looks like you're presenting UTF-8 data as Latin1 or Windows-1252.

Comment: I see the column default character set as 'utf8'

Comment: Thanks Tadman, Can you please help me how to change which it can be in readable format

Comment: got the solution ...
    convert(binary convert(str using latin1) using utf8)

Answer (score 0):

OP's self-answer (posted as a comment) :

> got the solution ... convert(binary convert(str using latin1) using utf8) – Sql_Learner Jun 4 '14 at 19:58