# How to correctly read accented characters in Java with Servlets and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, character-encoding

My problem is, I can't insert correctly accented characters (á é í ó ú ñ) in my DB.

This is my **output console**:

[image: Picture 1]

As you can see the original text of the column `grupo` is `Cómputo integrál`.

The same happens in my **output web browser**:

[image: Picture 2]

This is my **servlet** code:

```
//Save the input form and search immediately
tx.begin();
Salon get = (Salon) session.get(salon.getClass(), 1);
tx.commit();

request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");//Línea para que se ingresen de forma correcta los caracteres.
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");

try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
{
    out.println("Salida de texto: " + get.getGrupo());
}
```

This is my **meta** html code:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And my **DB** is configured with the collation `utf8 - utf8_spanish_ci`

What I can do to save, insert, show and update correctly?

Comment: Why have you set the content type to ISO-8859-1 if you're actually using UTF-8? See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/ for details about what you should do to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The same applies if I change the content type to utf8.

Comment: Additionally, "As you can see the original text of the column grupo is Cómputo integrál" - no, we can't see that at all. We can only see the broken text. So we don't know whether the problem is *reading* it or *writing* it.

Comment: Voting to close:  Mojibake.  See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881114/how-to-avoid-junk-garbage-characters-while-reading-data-from-multiple-languages/29907185#29907185) for discussion and solution, including how to recover the data via a pair of `ALTER TABLEs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in the URL of the connection to the database:

> jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?**useUnicode=yes**&**characterEncoding=UTF-8**