# Retrieve unicode data from mysql using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, unicode

I cannot retrieve my unicode data from my mysql database. Help me. I have briefed down about how I created my unicode database table and how I tried to retrieve the unicode data.

This is how stored my Unicode (tamil) data into my mysql in xampp server Windows 8:

- I created a database using `create database library`
- Inside that database, I created a table using

  ```
  create table book 
  (
      id integer primary key auto_increment,
      name text default '',
      auth text default ''
  ) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```
- I had a .csv file encoded in utf-8. The following image shows its content.

  [image: csv file content - image]
- I have input my .csv into the table using the following query

  ```
  load data local infile 'C:\\Users\\Ramvignesh\\Desktop\\lib1.csv' into table library.book fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n' (id,name,auth);
  ```
- The following image shows how the data had been stored in my db table.

  [image: db table - image]

This is how I tried retrieving my Unicode (tamil) data:

- I created a jsp code which is as follows.

  ```
  <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <%
              PreparedStatement st=null;
              ResultSet rs=null;
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","");
    %>
              <table> 
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>id</th>
                      <th>name</th>
                      <th>author</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
    <%
              st= con.prepareStatement("select * from book");
              rs=st.executeQuery();
              while(rs.next()){

    %>
              <tr>
                  <td><% out.println(rs.getString(1));%></td>
                  <td><% out.println(rs.getString(2));%></td>
                  <td><% out.println(rs.getString(3));%></td>
              </tr>
    <%    
             }
    %>
          </tbody>
          </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- The following image shows the output for my code.

  [image: jsp page - image]

Answer (score 1):

Please provide machine-readable versions of those images.

Please do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...;` for some mangled text so we can figure out whether the data was even stored correctly.

Meanwhile, I will guess that you have Mojibake.  See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881114/how-to-avoid-junk-garbage-characters-while-reading-data-from-multiple-languages/29907185#29907185) for discussion and solution, including how to recover the data via a pair of `ALTER TABLEs`.