# MySQL Import CSV in UTF-8 charset without problems?

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, import, character-encoding

I'm doing an import of my csv file in my mysql database (**interclassement utf8_general_ci**). The **file use UTF-8 charset encoding** and **I set UTF-8 on the import** page... but that is the result : **"é" ==> "Ã©"** ....

So my question is : why I have this basic problem on charset with a config import seems good ? **Have you an idea to solve the problem ?**

Thanks for help :)

The result  :

[image]

I do this :

[image]

Server version: 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
with Wamp
On Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: How do you import your csv file?

Comment: I set a print screen in my initial post to see you how I do :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid Junk/garbage characters while reading data from multiple languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881114/how-to-avoid-junk-garbage-characters-while-reading-data-from-multiple-languages)

Comment: Voted to close:  Mojibake.  See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881114/how-to-avoid-junk-garbage-characters-while-reading-data-from-multiple-languages/29907185#29907185) for discussion and solution, including how to recover the data via a pair of `ALTER TABLEs`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Partially SOLVED :

The problem was :
I create database with the the default collation (swedish).
So I was changed the database collation, the table collation and the columns collation BUT SEEMS Import was ever in swedish.

The problem "SOLVED" with :
Re-create all the database with the good collation.

In fact the problem is the COLLATION SELECT FIELD FILLED WITH SWEDISH BY DEFAULT when you create a database. The solution can be that MySQL team update this with an empty select by default.

Comment: You mean `CHARACTER SET`, not `COLLATION`.