# PHP - MySQL - Java - Ensuring charset uniformity

Tags: java, php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I am having an issue where I send some text from a java program to a PHP page, which uploads the text to a MySQL database, and I later retrieve the text in the java program from the MySQL database (through another PHP page). The issue is that I think the MySQL database isn't using the same charset (utf-8) as the java program and the PHP page.

When I send the string "This is a super—long dash" to the PHP page, it returns from the MySQL database as "This is a superâ€”long dash".

I know the first PHP page is receiving the correct string, because I use "echo $_POST[xxx];" to make sure.

I also use the line:

```
"mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8"
```

When creating the PDO to connect to the MySQL database.

I have checked the MySQL database and the string there is "This is a superùlong dash" which leads me to believe it must be some problem with the MySQL, not the PHP or Java.

I tried to correct this by using the fixUTF8 function in the solution here: [Detect encoding and make everything UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8) by Sebastián Grignoli. However, as a result I get "This is a super?long dash".

**EDIT:**

Here is my PHP code for uploading to MySQL:

```
<?php

$servername = "**********";
$username = "**********";
$password = "**********";
$dbname = "**********";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO authors (first_name, middle_name, last_name, blurb)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->execute(array("$_POST[firstName]", "$_POST[middleName]", "$_POST[lastName]", "$_POST[blurb]"));

    echo "New author created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is what `SHOW CREATE TABLE authors` provides:

[image]

Comment: your database have utf_general_ci encoding? column with string too? You created record from java application or what? Need to be created in utf8 too

Answer (score 0):

When `super—long` comes out `superâ€”long`, you have Mojibake.

This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (Or possibly it was inherited from the table/database.)  (It should have been `utf8`.)

The **fix for the data** is a "2-step ALTER".

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.

Unfortunately, if you have a lot of columns to work with, it will take a lot of ALTERs.  You can (should) `MODIFY` all the necessary columns to `VARBINARY` for a single table in a pair of `ALTERs`.

The **fix for the code** is to establish utf8 as the connection; this depends on the api used in PHP.  The `ALTERs` will change the column definition.

[How to avoid Junk/garbage characters while reading data from multiple languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881114/how-to-avoid-junk-garbage-characters-while-reading-data-from-multiple-languages)
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#how_mangling_happens_on_insert

Comment: When I use the ALTER statements on my MySQL database, I check the database again right after (I only have 4 columns) and the weird characters are still there. Also, when I try to add text with the super—long dash from the java through the PHP, it still shows up as the weird characters. Also, I already establish utf8 as the connection in the PHP by adding "charset=utf8", see my original post.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...`.  The em-dash _should_ be hex `E28094` if it is correctly encoded in utf8.  If it is "double encoded" (bad), it will be `C3A2E282ACE2809D`.

Comment: It shows the hex as: 546869732069732061207375706572E280946C6F6E672064617368. After using the alter statements it still shows as the same hex. What does this mean?

Comment: Nevermind, that was with a full sentence. This time I put as an entry just the em-dash. When I use the `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` command, it shows: `ù | E28094`. So it is the wrong character but the correct hex. What does this mean?

Comment: Interesting...  I do not see how that hex could display as `ù`.  But it pretty clearly says that the data was stored correctly, then not fetched and/or displayed correctly.  (Usually the problem is on the `INSERT` side.)  More after I scratch my head.

Comment: Check the issues in [Best Practice](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#best_practice), especially the `meta` tag and other "output" issues.

Comment: A _guess_ is that something other than utf8 or latin1 is somehow being specified during the output, and that leads to the `ù`.  I've checked the obvious mistakes using those character sets.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing that the page you linked seems to suggest is to use SET NAMES. I tried using this to no avail. Anyway, I believe using "charset=utf8" when creating the PDO should do the same thing in recent versions of PHP, as I am using. See my edited post for my full PHP script for adding to the MySQL database. I don't see what I could change or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have another example?  Maybe with more than one test case, I can find a pattern.

Comment: Alright so I went through a couple utf8 characters from this site: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm. And I found that most things seem to turn into a ? in the MySQL database. These include the characters that have hex: C482, C483, C7AF, CBAD, E1B481, E1B881, E1BA9E, E1BFBC, E28096. Two characters I found that didn't appear as ? were hex: E280A0 (appeared as: å) and E280A1 (appeared as: ç). In all cases the hex was correct in the database but the character shown was either ? or a character that doesn't correspond to the uft8 hex.

Comment: hmmm...  I tried the double-dagger (`E280A1`) with 36 charsets with `CONVERT(UNHEX('E280A1') USING %s)`; none came out with `ç`.  Nor do any conversions _start with_ `ç`, which could imply a truncation.  I tried some other things, too; again with no good clues.  Working the other way, I found no way to turn `ç` into `‡`.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add some code for the "output" side, such as the `SELECT` and the `<meta...>`.

Comment: And the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`).  (Yes, I am fishing for straws.)

Comment: This problem is so weird! I'm not even using the output side PHP code anymore. I am just inputting the data and then viewing the data in mysql through command prompt with `SELECT * FROM ...`. I used `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` and saw that the default charset was latin1, so I changed it to be utf8 and then tried the tests again and still had the same results (probably because I had done the alter statement earlier to change the appropriate column to utf8). I edited the OP to add a screenshot of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` statement now.

Comment: Nothing strange in the `CREATE TABLE`.  To help with debugging (from PHP), use    `$hex = unpack('H*', $text);
   echo implode('', $hex);`  to display hex.

Comment: Using this, the php echos the correct hexes for the various characters. It must be something with the database but I can't figure out what.