# HTML link to internet does not work

Tags: html

Trying a very basic link through HTML to internet:

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>
```

No matter what website I try to link to my browser says ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and the detail

No webpage was found for the web address: file:///Users/stevemcc101/Dropbox/html/â€œhttps://www.google.comâ€

So my browser is always picking up the path to the dropbox folder (or any other folder I save the document in) and not linking direct to the URL.

Sorry I know a basic query but just starting to learn HTML and can't get around this issue.  Please help!

Comment: It sounds like you're using smart quotes  (exacerbated by an encoding problem).  Don't do that.

Comment: What sort of editor are you using to write your HTML?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%84%A2-showing-on-page-instead-of

Comment: actually with double quotes also working right?..

Comment: why is a request for http://www.google.com looking for file:///Users/stevemcc101/Dropbox/html/â€œhttps://www.google.comâ€ ? Can you post the full HTML source?

Answer (score 1):

Try without the quotes like so:

```
<p><a href=http://www.google.com>Google</a></p>
```

if that works then the issue is with your quotes