# How do â€™ , âˆ, Ã, âˆ’, â€˜ conversions in Java?

Tags: java, android, string

I've huge String array to display via using `Textview`. This String array contain some anonymous char like â€™ , âˆ, Ã, âˆ’, â€˜ etc. But it has no meaning in English please help me how to decode these char in actual meaning.

I've already use UTF-8 encoding but not work.

```
private final static Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

public static String getUTF8Encoded(String targetString) {
    String resultant = "";
    try {
        return new String(encodeUTF8(targetString), UTF8_CHARSET);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return resultant;
    }
}

private static final byte[] encodeUTF8(String string) {
    return string.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
}
```

Comment: Do these characters have corresponding Latin alphabets? For instance something similar to Cyrillic alphabets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

try with this:

```
Charset.forName("windows-1252");
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents%28java.lang.String%29)

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents("Añ");
```

returns `An`.

---

**another solution:**

this function converts all accented characters into their deAccented counterparts followed by their combining diacritics. Now you can use a regex to strip off the diacritics.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String deAccent(String str) {
String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```