# Why did my database change some text characters to some funny code?

Tags: mysql

My database used to display text normally. Now, for some reason it is displaying some text characters in a funny way. For example, the apostrophe

`' is displayed as â€™
 - is displayed as â€”`

I didn't update anything in my database, so that is why I am wondering how this could have happened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Comment: I looked at this question, and I think it is different. I have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> in my php file. I also checked the database and it is how it is stored. It was not like that 5 days ago.

Comment: Edit into your question a minimal example showing how you fetch the field from your database and display it on the page. What is the schema of your table (specifically the column you're reading from)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: I do have this at the top of my document.

Comment: mysql_query("SET COLUMN_NAME 'utf8'"); before adding/retreiving from the database.

 php function urlencode($text) was applied when displaying, so  removed that .

and  also make sure that the headers for the page and the ajax request/response were all utf8.