# The browser shows "â€™" whenever I type single or quotation mark in the content of my HTML code. What's wrong?

Tags: html

The browser shows "â€™" whenever I type single or quotation mark in the content of my HTML code. What's wrong?.

For example, in my html file, it writes `<p>"</p>`.
The browser will print `â€™`.

There's no relevant information on this problem anywhere online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Comment: *There's no relevant information on this problem anywhere online.* Actually, there are hundreds of SO questions and blog posts. Make sure your file is saved as UTF-8, your page's encoding is set properly, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of encoding problems. Your text editor must be encoding in encoding type other than UTF-8. You should change your browser's and text editor's encoding type to UTF-8. And also don't forget to add a meta tag for encoding in your  HTML file.