# Remove ™ ® using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, workday-api

HI I have a scenario where I need to remove special characters as well as Latin Characters. I was able to strip out Latin and few special characters. But for some reason, ™ is getting converted to TM. How do I remove that using xslt? Here is my code and function

```
 <Last_Name xtt:fixedLength="30" xtt:required="true" xtt:severity="error" xtt:align="left"><xsl:value-of select="lancet:stripSpecialChars(replace(normalize-unicode(translate(wd:Last_Name, ',', ''), 'NFKD'), '⁄', '/'))"/></Last_Name>
```

**function**

```
<xsl:function name="lancet:stripSpecialChars">
<xsl:param name="string" />
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;™,.?[]=- +   /\ '"/>
<xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-unicode($string, 'NFKD'), '\P{IsBasicLatin}', '')"/>
```

What am I expecting?

**INPUT:** DEâ€™ERIKA

**OUTPUT:** (Right Now with my code) -> DEATMERIKA

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:** DEAERIKA (My code is eliminating Latin characters and few symbols)

Comment: Why? You should fix your code to handle Unicode instead.

Comment: Your clients and partners are going to be _very_ upset if you remove their trademark assertions. That could get you into legal trouble. Don't do that.

Comment: And how is JavaScript/Java involved?

Comment: @msanford This is something that happens within the file feed into different systems. It's not something I am removing trademarks. For example, if I am sending a file From X system to Y system, for many reasons, File generated from X will have certain special characters and in order to load the file into Y that has to be removed

Comment: @GopiNaidu Do you mean that those characters are _added incorrectly by some process but not in the original data_?

Comment: Yes. Maybe added by employee during the onboarding, while completing the data related to personal information, etc

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing these characters because you are using the incorrect code page somewhere: the input XML is encoded as UTF-8 but the display system assumes ASCII instead. The solution is to perform a conversion or to make the display applcation use UTF-8.

Do not delete the â€™ characters! If a user enters e.g. a letter with an accent (ï) that is not present in the ASCII code page, the system will render something like â€™.

Specifically, â€™ is a right single quote. So the user input was:

DE'ERIKA (which is a valid name in many languages).

Rendering this as DEERIKA or (worse) DEATMERIKA is **incorrect!**

If you remove these characters, you're deleting part of the input. That's like proposing to change your name to "Gop Nadu" because your system can't render the 'i'.

[Related question that explains what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of)