# webpack bundle invalid char

Tags: webpack

webpack bundle,  invalid characters instead of text, attached the screenshot [image: see the invalid char]

```
â€¦
```

running in dev no issues (non-minified version)

```
<li class="disabled"><a role="button" href="#" tabindex="-1" style="pointer-events: none;"><span aria-label="More">…</span></a></li>
```

same using webpack-bundle  (minified version) replaces ...   with  â€¦

```
<li class="disabled"><a role="button" href="#" tabindex="-1" style="pointer-events: none;"><span aria-label="More">â€¦</span></a></li>
```

please advice what could be causing this issue, how to resolve

Comment: It sounds like it has to do with Unicode encoding, see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of) and try using three period characters instead of [… which is the unicode ellipsis](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm).

Comment: after adding the charset utf-8 from server-side , issue is resolved