# How do I fix an issue with my HTML code?. The screen displays text I haven't written

Tags: html

The text I have written doesn't match the text that is shown on the website. 
for example, here is the text as written;

```
<h1 class="title2"> Get food fast - not fast food.</h1>
<p class="title2"> Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!</p>
```

Here is the text as displayed;

> Hello, weâ€™re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service.Â We know youâ€™re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, weâ€™re really good at it, we promise!

I have no idea why this is happening or what to do about it, any advice would be much appreciated, thanks for all help given.

Comment: Try this [post's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add meta tag for characters UT8 `<meta charset="utf-8">` in you all the html files or in header file.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `<meta charset="utf-8">` in head.
Or just set the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` on the server-side if you have access.

You can also do add in .htaccess: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` 
more info here http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you used an *element* to show it.

Such as

```html
<p>Get food fast - not fast food. Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!</p>

<!-- Or use the heading elements -->

<h1>Get food fast - not fast food. Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!</h1>

<!-- You can use the heading elements all the way up until <h6>
```

I hope this will resolve your problem

If this doesn't work than in your head element put this: