# A curly quote (’) turns into â€™ when submitted in a form

Tags: mysql, database, forms, utf-8

When users submit a form on my site a curly quote (’) turns into â€™, and an em-dash turns into â€”.

The form page contains this code that store the details to the MySQL Database:

```
$serializeArray = serialize($itemDetails);
update_option('art_'.$latest_order_id,$serializeArray);
```

The thank you page that extracts the information from the database and sends the details by email contains this code:

```
$serialized_array = get_option('art_'.$_GET['id']);
$itemDetails = unserialize($serialized_array);
```

I have the Content-Type set to UTF-8 in my  tag.
The MySQL tables are configured to use UTF-8.

When I check the details in the MySQL Database, the database contains the ’ character, NOT â€™.
The â€™ appears when the data is extracted from the database.

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored