# How to convert â€™ to apostrophe(') in Java

Tags: java

I want to convert â€™ to apostrophe(') in Java.

**Input:**
String s = "masterâ€™s degree"

It should be:

master's degree

Comment: This is caused by reading text data with the wrong encoding. It would be better to fix the buggy code that read the string in incorrectly rather than try to patch it up after the fact.

Comment: See [encoding - "â€™" showing on page instead of " ' " - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Answer (score -3):

```
  s =   s.replace("â€™","'");
```

Comment: please have a look at the comment to the question

Comment: ammm did i give wrong answer?

Comment: yes in my opinion but I'm 1 in 400k !