# json-simple retrieving unwanted characters

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to access a json  array using **json-simple** dependency

```
productObject.get("description")
```

productObject is a jsonObject .

Gives me "Bhadohi, the â€˜Carpet city of Indiaâ€™" unwanted characters .

In the json file it is "Bhadohi, the ‘Carpet city of India’"

how can I get the actual value as it is in the file.

Comment: Duplicate of ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477452/%c3%a2%e2%82%ac-showing-on-page-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

Change the IDE encoding to UTF-8 .
This solved my problem .