# the term 'â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When testing my PowerShell script in Visual Code I got the following error:

the term 'â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,

However, finally I tested the same code in ISE and I did not get the same error!

```
try {

    $file_name = Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\sample\uk-500-UTF.csv" 
    $csv_data = Import-Csv -Path $file_name.FullName -Delimiter ','

foreach ($line in $csv_data){
    $line
    break
}

}
catch{
    Write-Host "Ran into an issue: $($PSItem.ToString())"

}
```

Comment: you saved the file in the wrong encoding. [“â€™” showing on page instead of “ ' ”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2477452/995714)

Comment: As aside, `Get-ChildItem` using a file's FullName is pointless because a file does not have child items.. Only folders and drives have them

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with Visual Code. When I re-typed the same code, in another section of the same file, no error.

I hope this helps others who face a similar issue.