# how to change "â€“" these values to original in aws s3 bucket by using snowflake file format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, special-characters

Can you some one help me on the below mentioned issue from Snowflake file format to AWS S3 bucket.

I have requirement to unload data from Snowflake to AWS S3 bucket as a CSV format.
During this process i am using COPY INTO command to load data from Snowflake to s3 bucket. Once the
data got unloaded from snowflake to S3 bucket I am getting these type of special character's in my out put file.

Original value in Snowflake : Raleigh, NC - E&S PED
Output value in S3 bucket CSV file : Raleigh, NC â€“ E&S PED

Copy command :

```
copy into @aws_s3_to_snf/SNF_S3_WB_STL.csv
from AAW.ACS_CLS_MART.SNF_S3_WB_STL
max_file_size = 2000000
overwrite = true
single = true
detailed_output = true
header = true
FILE_FORMAT = ( type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1
                compression=NONE FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"');
```

I want to show the original value in AWS S3 Bucket.
Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Make sure the encoding is UTC-8 throughout your pipeline. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477460/3412322

Comment: Hi Daniel, than you for quick response, I am using this parameter in snowflake file format is "encoding=UTF8", it is not working for me still i am getting same issue.

Comment: You need to know the encoding of the files you are loading. Certain encodings will have characters that UTF-8 will not handle. The  â€“ character is a dead giveaway that you have the wrong encoding.

Comment: If it is possible can you please send the example to how to handle this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: " â€“" appears when you try to read UTF-8 formatted text but display it in ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252.    Either you're accidentally converting UTF-8 to 1252 before storing it in AWS, or your AWS bucket is storing in 1252, or the bucket is UTF-8 and something between there and the browser is converting it to 1252 before displaying the output.

Comment: (...I may have that backwards, now that I think of it.  Was the original content maybe 1252 encoded and getting incorrectly converted to UTF-8?)

Comment: The actual value is "Raleigh, NC - E&S PED" from snowflake. When ever I copy this values to AWS S3 bucket it is changed to "Raleigh, NC â€“ E&S PED" this. Don't know how to handle this type of scenario, I want to show actual value same as snowflake.

Comment: It sounds to me like whatever text viewer you are using to view your file on S3 is not viewing the file as UTF-8.  Snowflake's only encoding for a `COPY INTO LOCATION` is UTF-8 and the data is stored in Snowflake as UTF-8, so I can't imagine that anything is being done to the file that isn't UTF-8 except for perhaps how you are viewing the file itself.