# Trouble with quotes when converting HTML to an NSAttributedString in Swift

Tags: html, swiftui

To convert a string of HTML into an NSAttributedString, I'm using this code:

```
if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(self.utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            return AttributedString(attributedString)
```

but when I do, the single quotes in my text are coming out as â€™

Is there anything I can do to make them decode properly? It makes my text look like cartoon swearing.

Comment: This is because what you have is not a single quote character, but rather a "right single quotation mark" - a different character that may look like a quote. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477480/5318223)

Comment: I couldn't figure out why they were coming out wrong since I was using utf8. Then Ir realized I hadn't looked at my HTML stuff in a while. Sure enough, it didn't have an encoding format specified. Thanks.